# Prove that $\omega + \omega_1 = \omega \cdot \omega_1 = \omega^{\omega_1} = \omega_1$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am assuming already that
a) the union of countably many countable sets is countable and 
b) $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal, so $x < \omega_1$ if and only if $x$ is a countable ordinal.

I'm not sure if it is relevant but this question also allows The Axiom of Choice.

Thanks

Comment: @Antoine: These are ordinal operations.

Comment: @C.K: Do you mean $\omega^{\omega_1}$? Because $\omega_1^\omega$ is strictly larger than $\omega_1$.

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @Antoine: I have read about this briefly in a Classic Set Theory textbook but I thought this was Ordinal Arithmetic, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes sorry, the title has now been edited.

Comment: I haven't gotten very far. I noted by induction that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are countable ordinals, then so is $\alpha ^ \beta$ but I'm not sure how to apply that when working with $\omega$.

Comment: If $\omega^{\omega_1}=\sup\{\omega^\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\}$, and all the ordinals within that set we take $\sup$ over are countable, then this $\sup$ is at most $\omega_1$ itself. Now show that it cannot be anything less than $\omega_1$ and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** Recall the induction definition of *all* ordinal arithmetic. If $\delta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\alpha\square\delta=\sup\{\alpha\square\gamma\mid\gamma<\delta\}$ (where $\square$ can be addition, multiplication or exponentiation). Now prove the following lemma, and you're about done:

> **Lemma.** If $\square$ is any ordinal arithmetic operation, and at least one of $\alpha,\beta$ is infinite, then $|\alpha\square\beta|=\max\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\}$.

Comment: I have a kind of different but related question. Is it true that $\sum_{i\in\omega_1}\alpha_i=\sup\{\sum_{i\in\gamma}\alpha_i : \gamma\lt\omega_1\} $?

Comment: Are you talking about ordinals or cardinals?

Comment: Ordinals. sorry I forgot to mention it.